# Separate code between different versions of Mac OS X?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, macros

I want some code tobe compiled under 10.6 and below but not 10.7 and above.

For example:

```
#ifdef current version is MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_6 or below

// do this

elif current version is MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_7 or above 

//do that

#endif
```

Can someone help me ge proper macros for it? I looked into [AvailabilityMacros.h](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CarbonHeaders/CarbonHeaders-18.1/AvailabilityMacros.h) but was not able to figure out proper ifdef.

I have a dynamic library, and it cannot be loaded under 10.7 and above but loads properly under 10.6. This is due to private symbol `_CGContextAppendPath`. I want to keep it using under 10.6 and below but avoid its use in 10.7 and below. This is because `_CGContextAppendPath` symbol is not present on 10.7 and above.

I used,

```
SInt32 version = 0;
Gestalt( gestaltSystemVersion, &version );

bool lionabove = ( version >= 0x1070 );
```

did not work.

Comment: Your question isn't clear; you want some code to be compiled if the deployment target of your project is 10.6 or lower?

Comment: What happens when trying to load it under 10.7?

Comment: dlopen() return null. But if i comment the use of CGContextAppendPath(), it works fine. This is because that symbol is not present on 10.7 and above.

Comment: Then why not just check whether `dlopen()` returns `NULL`, and if yes, execute an alternative code path?

Comment: code is in dynamic library which should be loaded by calling dlopen().

Comment: So you have access to the source code of the dynamic library? Then I suggest weak linking the library and the executable to CoreGraphics.framework. Then it should also be able to be loaded on 10.7. In the code that uses `_CGContextAppendPath`, check if `&_CGContextAppendPath != NULL`, and if not, don't use it. But keep in mind that using private APIs in general is a BAD idea.

Comment: See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Configuring/configuring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000163i-CH1-107837 and http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002000-1114537-BABHHJBC from the links I sent you.

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Objective C, the go-to route would be to check the availability of specific APIs via e.g. `[object respondsToSelector:]`.

For the C library you are using, weak-link to `CoreGraphics.framework` (so the loading doesn't fail when some functions aren't present) and check for availability of the function in question via `&_CGContextAppendPath != NULL`.

Details in http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Configuring/configuring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000163i-CH1-107837 and http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002000-1114537-BABHHJBC.

Comment: Please look at the tags and read the question.  It's tagged as `osx` and `cocoa`, and the question explicitly says `MAC_OS_X_VERSION`.

Comment: Yes, and I presume that MacGeek has the misunderstand that different code gets created for different OS versions.

Comment: I think what MacGeek is saying that he wants different lines of code executed that's decided during runtime, not compile time if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: That's exactly what I answered by telling him to check for `[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]` at runtime...

Comment: Yes I guess, I misunderstand that different code gets created for different OS versions. But its a 'C' library cannot use objective c code in it.

Comment: @MrMage theAmateurProgrammer is right; `UIDevice` is an `iOS` class, not `OSX`.

Answer (score 1):

Apple introduced a new `Availability.h` macro file for iOS and Mac OS 10.6 and above (located in `<SDK>/usr/include/Availability.h`). You can do what you are asking like this:

```
#if __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < 1070
    // code to run up through 10.6
#else
    // code to run on 10.7 or higher
#endif
```

Note that this macro is also available (which might be preferable depending on your logic):

```
#if __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 1070
    // code to run on 10.7 or above
#else
    // code to run below 10.7
#endif
```

The documentation for this is here: [Conditionally Compiling for Different SDKs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002000-1114741-CJADDEIB), particularly worth looking at if you are mixing iOS and Mac OS X code. I also highly recommend reading the header file mentioned above.